# How to exclude a TV series from Google's search result?

Tags: google-search

I am searching Google images for "friends" but most of the results relate to the "Friends" TV series.

Is it possible to exclude these results?

Comment: @pnuts Well, I am more specifically looking for images denoting "friendship". I am still curious though, how the unwanted results of "friends" can be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try excluding terms (moderately) specific to the *Friends* TV series, say:

```
friends -tv -joey -phoebe -jennifer -monica -chandler -schwimmer -courteney -lisa -matt
```